# Regex for matching and grouping SPARQL triples

Tags: python, regex, sparql

I am trying to write a regular expression to match SPARQL triplets in the context for semantic data, e.g:

> ```
>    ?art rdf:date ?date.
>    ?art music:performer ?myPerformer.
>    ?art event:place ?place.
> ```

So far I have been able to match the characters consistent in every example (question mark at the start of the 1st and 3rd word, semi-colon in the middle word, and a full stop at the end) using this:

> [^\w ]

I am however unable to get all 3 words grouped together in the match, what am I missing in my approach to this?

Comment: It's worth noting that any of these triples might have a CURIe or a full URI or a variable (`?asdf`) in any of the three positions. Also, SPARQL graph patterns do not require each triple to be written as such — as with Turtle, there might be multi-value predicates (separated with commas) or multi-predicate subjects (separated with semicolons), among other syntactical complications. RegEx are unlikely to help you very far.

Comment: TallTed is right. You need a proper parser and not a simple REGEX in order to ensure completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the question mark::

```
>>> re.search(r'(\?\w+\s\w+:\w+\s\?\w+)', '?art rdf:date ?date.').groups()
('?art rdf:date ?date',)
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank-you! To match a single word starting with a question mark, would I use '(\?\w)'?

Comment: @Masutatsu almost, you need to add a repeat char, like plus or star `(\?\w+)`